# Mixed linear model to fit soil samples taken over two sampling points

Tags: mixed-model, meta-analysis, mixed-random-variable

I have the following data for two different sampling points:

proteins from three different drought intensities (control, moderate and severe), and also using two diferent treatments (sterilized and non sterilized) in climate chamber pots and was told to perform a mixed linear model to see the effect of the sampling points over the proteins. I am super new to mixed linear models and what I am reading out there is not really helping me out.  How should I design this model?

I tought in using:

lmer(Proteins_µg.g.soil ~ Sampling_point + drought intensity + Treatment + (1|Pot),
data = Raw_data, REML=FALSE)

but I am not sure if that is right, could someone help me? Also, how do I interpret that?

Comment: If each of the proteins was only in one of the drought intensity groups, and also only in one of the treatment groups, but each pot was used for several proteins, your code seems correct to me. Make sure you have drought intensity and treatment variables representing the variable type you want (I assume both need to be factors). Sampling point is meant to be a continuous predictor, I assume?